# Docker installed on Windows Server 2019 But getting ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

Tags: docker, powershell, docker-compose

I'm running Amazon Workspace AL2023 and have managed to install Docker via powershell as an admininstrator as I get in the powershell terminal:

> Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
> [2023-08-22T15:25:44.028216600Z][docker-credential-desktop.system][W] Windows version might not be up-to-date: The system cannot find the file specified.
> latest: Pulling from library/hello-world
> 86fab75eb466: Pull complete
> 13488e9375be: Pull complete
> 6ed4b8ef30c3: Pull complete
> Digest: sha256:dcba6daec718f547568c562956fa47e1b03673dd010fe6ee58ca806767031d1c
> Status: Downloaded newer image for hello-world:latest

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:

1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
   (windows-amd64, nanoserver-1809)
3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
   executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
   to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run a Windows Server container with:
PS C:> docker run -it mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1809 powershell

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

And when I go to the `Services.app` I see

> Docker Desktop Service Running

However when trying Docker Desktop i.e. the Windows app (do I even need DD if the Docker Desktop Service is Running?)

I get this...

[image]

Finally when I try to run `docker-compose up -d` in my AL2023 shell (using zsh) I get:

```
ERROR: Couldn't connect to Docker daemon at http+docker://localhost - is it running?

If it's at a non-standard location, specify the URL with the DOCKER_HOST environment variable.
```

My goal for this is to install **and** run a `postgres` container, to connect to a `nest.js` app.

But I can't seem to get the docker part right. PLEASE HELP!